# Using Capybara how to disable "wait_for_pending_requests" as it raise an error

Tags: capybara

I'm using Capybara with WebMock and a proxy (Sinatra) to test a remote app.
I'm not stubbing the requests but using WebMock to assert requests. I've assigned the proxy to capybara.app and added to the chrome driver so the requests will be forwarded to the proxy.

My problem is that sometimes I have pending requests which will raise the following error:

```
Failure/Error: raise "Requests did not finish in 60 seconds"
```

I wonder how can I disable this error?
Also how can I change the hard coded timeout which is 60 (which will block the continuation of the test anyway)

```
Timeout.timeout(60) { sleep(0.01) while @middleware.pending_requests? }
```

capybara.rb:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require_relative 'sinatra_proxy'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb' if !isWindows

Capybara.server_port = 9980

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  http_client = isWindows ? nil : Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Curb.new
  options = {
      http_client: http_client,
      browser: :chrome,

      switches: [
          "--proxy-server=0.0.0.0:9980",
          "--disable-web-security",
          '--user-agent="Chrome under Selenium for Capybara"',
          "--start-maximized",
          '--no-sandbox',
      ]
  }
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, options
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.app = SinatraProxy.new
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 8
```

Sinatra proxy:

```
require "sinatra"
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

file = File.read 'config.json'
config_json = JSON.parse(file)
HOST = 'remote_app'
PORT = '80'
HEADERS_NOT_TO_PROXY = %w(transfer-encoding)

class SinatraProxy < Sinatra::Base
    # configure :development do
    #   register Sinatra::Reloader
    # end

    def request_headers
        request.env.select {|k,v| k.start_with? 'HTTP_'}
                .collect {|pair| [pair[0].sub(/^HTTP_/, ''), pair[1]]}
                .to_h # Ruby 2.1
                .merge('CONTENT-TYPE' => request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] || 'application/json')
    end

    proxy = lambda do
        # puts "REQUEST HEADERS #{request_headers}"

        uri = URI.parse(request.url)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(HOST, PORT)
        response = http.send_request(
                request.request_method.upcase,
                uri.request_uri,
                request.body.read,
                request_headers)

        response_headers = {}
        response.to_hash.each{|k,v| response_headers[k]=v.join unless HEADERS_NOT_TO_PROXY.include?(k) }

        status response.code
        headers response_headers
        headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
        # puts "RESPONSE HEADERS #{response_headers}, BODY: #{response.body}"
        body response.body
    end

    get '/*', &proxy
    post '/*', &proxy
    patch '/*', &proxy
    put '/*', &proxy
    delete '/*', &proxy

    options "*" do
        headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'
        halt 200
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the timeout for waiting during reset, however you shouldn't be setting `Capybara.app` to your proxy app to start with.  `Capybara.app` is meant for your AUT (application under test) where any requests that hang for more than 60 seconds after being told to quit is definitely an error.  Since your proxy isn't your AUT just run it separately and tell Capybara not to run a server/app.

```
Capybara.run_server = false

Thread.new do  
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(SinatraProxy.new, Host: '0.0.0.0', Port: 9980) # You might need/want other options here or to use thin/webrick/etc 
end
```